# NetworkExtension NEKit NETunnelProviderManager VPN Connect error 4097

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, networkextension

all.
there is a error about NEKIT, when I startVPNTunnelWithOptions.

My project is a Objective-C program. Then I use Cartfile to integration NEKit Framework and linked Binary with All libraries to my PacketTunnel target. For Example this pic.
 [Project Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/652cz.png)

And my PacketTunnelProvider target with Swift language
[PacketTunnelProvider target Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYo0Y.png)

There are my connect method 
[connect method Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgepk.png)

And then there are logs

```
connection to plug-in <private>(283BAAB5-BE93-42D1-A222-408B36BFAD40) lost

Hub connection error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to 
service named com.tyria.supplyCrate.PacketTunnel" UserInfo= 
{NSDebugDescription=connection to service named 
com.tyria.supplyCrate.PacketTunnel}

Failed to start extension com.tyria.supplyCrate.PacketTunnel: Error 
Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named 
com.tyria.supplyCrate.PacketTunnel" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to 
service named com.tyria.supplyCrate.PacketTunnel}
```

I don't know what reasons cause this problem. 
I double checked my info.plist and entitlements.

I also tryed to add the Nekit frameworks to my project target, and Frameworks select optional (when I select required there is a crash when i start the project) not work.

But when I create a Swift demo to archieve VPN connect. 
use the same BundleID, the save info.plist and entitlements. 
VPN Connect successful。
[My Swift Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ro5I.png)

I confused。 Please help me！ Thanks!